# node.js app on the heroku platform

Tags: node.js, heroku, web

I created a simple `Node.js` app following the [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs) offered by `Heroku`. When I try to run the command `heroku ps:scale worker=1` from within the application folder I get the following error message:

```
Scaling worker dynos... failed
 !    Resource not found
```

Any ideas what the problem may be? I checked my app's dashboard on `Heroku` and the commit is there and also a Dyno is allocated. The Procfile is identical to the one in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have a `worker` process defined in your procfile? The node tutorial doesn't have you add one I don't think. Try `heroku ps:scale web=1` instead.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I don't know how I did not see that. Guess I'm too tired and I should take a break. Thanks a lot!